# How to recover data from HD that shuts down?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have this Seagate 2.5" HD that stopped working without a warning, and I need to recover some data from it.

When I connect it to a hot swap SATA port, it works for a few seconds, and I can even browse folders and see what I need to recover, but then it simply shuts down 2 or 3 seconds later.

It feels like it's some sort of firmware fail-safe, shutting down the disk to prevent further damage or something, but at the same time it's preventing me from recovering data. I don't know what to look for online to access this problem so I'm dropping this question here.

Does anyone know what's going on and what I could do to recover data from this disk?

I'm considering buying one of same model and replace the circuit to see what happens but I'd rather not spend this money without knowing if it will do the trick.

Comment: This typically wouldn't be solved by anyone that didn't have a clean room and a spare identical working drive to use for parts.  If you purchase a new circuit, and replace it yourself, then you risk being unable to use any data recovery services (if you break the seal yourself they typically won't even take your case).

Comment: @ramhound - I've recovered data from cases like this - no clean room. Also, I don't think havenard is talking about opening platters, just replacing logic board. I do agree that anything he does can make it harder - or even impossible - for experts.

Comment: The circuit board can be replaced without removing any seals and without need of a clean room, you just remove 3 screws and it comes off. Some disks can be recovered just by cleaning the connectors between this board and the rest of the disk, but it doesn't seem to be the case here. Besides the fact that its shutting down, the disk looks great. It's not clicking, or taking long to access, no chips overheating or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer. Depending on the value of the data you may want to take it to a specialist - as what I propose has risks and could make things worse.

Get a disk at least as big as the dying one and a USB key. Put a Linux distro on the key and use (gnu) ddrescue to make a bit copy of the drive. Ddrescue can restart from where it left off when a crash occurs, read forwards and backwards, and generally get as much data off the disk as it can.

There are a couple of old tricks which have worked for me in the past. Put the disk in a Ziploc bag (to prevent condensation on electronics ) and put it in the fridge.  Very often this will increase your read time. Repeat as needed.   An even more contovertial idea - which I've not tried and would not recommend - would be to put the disk in the oven on low - this can theoretically reflow solder and fix some issues.

Buying a similar disk and swapping controllers might work, but won't necessarily - disk store key info in the controllers, and when you swap controllers you get wrong information.

My guess is the disk is in largely in tact but the controller has issues.